# Swift 2.2 - Count Black Pixels in UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, swift2, pixel

I need to count all the black pixels in `UIImage`. I have found a code that could work however it is written in Objective-C. I have tried to convert  it in swift but I get lots of errors and I cannot find the way of fix them.

Whats the best way to do this using Swift?

Simple Image[image]

Objective-C:

```
/**
 * Structure to keep one pixel in RRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAA format
 */

struct pixel {
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};

/**
 * Process the image and return the number of pure red pixels in it.
 */

- (NSUInteger) processImage: (UIImage*) image
{
    NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels = 0;

    // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold all the pixels

    struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
    if (pixels != nil)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
            (void*) pixels,
            image.size.width,
            image.size.height,
            8,
            image.size.width * 4,
            CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
        );

        if (context != NULL)
        {
            // Draw the image in the bitmap

            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

            // Now that we have the image drawn in our own buffer, we can loop over the pixels to
            // process it. This simple case simply counts all pixels that have a pure red component.

            // There are probably more efficient and interesting ways to do this. But the important
            // part is that the pixels buffer can be read directly.

            NSUInteger numberOfPixels = image.size.width * image.size.height;

            while (numberOfPixels > 0) {
                if (pixels->r == 255) {
                    numberOfRedPixels++;
                }
                pixels++;
                numberOfPixels--;
            }

            CGContextRelease(context);
        }

        free(pixels);
    }

    return numberOfRedPixels;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Much faster is to use Accelerate's `vImageHistogramCalculation` to get a histogram of the different channels in your image:

```
let img: CGImage = CIImage(image: image!)!.cgImage!

let imgProvider: CGDataProvider = img.dataProvider!
let imgBitmapData: CFData = imgProvider.data!
var imgBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(imgBitmapData)), height: vImagePixelCount(img.height), width: vImagePixelCount(img.width), rowBytes: img.bytesPerRow)

let alpha = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let red = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let green = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let blue = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)

let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let redPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: red) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let greenPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: green) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let bluePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: blue) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?

let rgba = [redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr, alphaPtr]

let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?>(mutating: rgba)
let error = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&imgBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
```

After this runs, `alpha`, `red`, `green`, and `blue` are now histograms of the colors in your image. If `red`, `green`, and `blue` each only have count in the 0th spot, while `alpha` only has count in the last spot, your image is black.

If you want to not even check multiple arrays, you can use `vImageMatrixMultiply` to combine your different channels:

```
let readableMatrix: [[Int16]] = [
    [3,     0,     0,    0]
    [0,     1,     1,    1],
    [0,     0,     0,    0],
    [0,     0,     0,    0]
]

var matrix: [Int16] = [Int16](repeating: 0, count: 16)

for i in 0...3 {
    for j in 0...3 {
        matrix[(3 - j) * 4 + (3 - i)] = readableMatrix[i][j]
    }
}
vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&imgBuffer, &imgBuffer, matrix, 3, nil, nil, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
```

If you stick this in before the histograming, your `imgBuffer` will be modified in place to average the RGB in each pixel, writing the average out to the B channel. As such, you can just check the `blue` histogram instead of all three.

(btw, the best description of `vImageMatrixMultiply` I've found is in the source code, like at https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/2d31dd8bdd670293b59869335d9f1f80ca2075e0/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Transform.h#L21)

Comment: Great answer - this should be accepted as the right answer. Works extremely quickly & accurately, tho in my implementation, it seems that the alpha channel (when it's solid black) has its only value in the last spot. Strange.

Comment: Oops, good catch: min value for RGB is black, but max value for alpha is totally visible. Will fix, thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice and fast. Should be the correct answer.

Comment: Your post was the one I relied on for a histogram function. Thanks! In Swift 5, though, I would get warnings about UnsafeMutablePointer. I glommed together your code with code from Apple's documentation and posted the Swift 5 version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562889/drawing-histogram-of-cgimage-in-swift-3/66369478#66369478

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue now, where I needed to determine if an image was 100% black. The following code will return the number of pure black pixels it finds in an image.

However, if you want to bump the threshold up, you can change the compare value, and allow it to tolerate a wider range of possible colors.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    var blackPixelCount: Int {
        var count = 0
        for x in 0..<Int(size.width) {
            for y in 0..<Int(size.height) {
                count = count + (isPixelBlack(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))) ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }

        return count
    }

    private func isPixelBlack(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        let pixelData = cgImage?.dataProvider?.data
        let pointerData: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo = Int(((size.width * point.y) + point.x)) * 4

        let maxValue: CGFloat = 255.0
        let compare: CGFloat = 0.01

        if (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo]) / maxValue) > compare { return false }
        if (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo + 1]) / maxValue) > compare { return false }
        if (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo + 2]) / maxValue) > compare { return false }

        return true
    }
}
```

You call this with:

```
let count = image.blackPixelCount
```

The one caveat is that this is a very slow process, even on small images.

Comment: You are doing an incredible amount of work for each pixel. There has to be a more efficient way; e.g. read the image's RGB data into an array with one call, and then scan that...

Comment: @NicolasMiari I agree, which is why I had the caveat at the bottom. I had to do something similar recently, but on very small images, so I could afford the performance hit. However, I'd love to see something faster.

Comment: I don't remember which APIs does UIImage have to access raw data, but I'm betting CGImageRef is better suited...