# Drawing histogram of CGImage in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, histogram, cgimage, accelerate-framework

I have a problem with `vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888` method while trying to convert library from Swift 2 to Swift 3 version. The problem is that the method accepts "histogram" argument only as

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?>
```

but Swift 3 construction

```
let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>>(mutating: rgba)
```

return unwrapped value, so I can't cast it to properly type.

The compiler error is:

> : Cannot invoke initializer for type
>   'UnsafeMutablePointer?>' with
>   an argument list of type '(mutating:
>   [UnsafeMutablePointer])'

Have you some ideas? I tried to add "?" to histogram constant but then I receive error:

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to
>   temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

there is some compiler suggestion but I have no idea how can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast to `UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?`:

```
let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
```

Complete, compiling example:

```
var inBuffer = vImage_Buffer() // set your buffer here

let alpha = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let red = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let green = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
let blue = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)

let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let redPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: red) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let greenPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: green) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
let bluePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: blue) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?

let rgba = [redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr, alphaPtr]

let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?>(mutating: rgba)
let error = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

// alpha, red, green, blue are set now
```

Comment: So, for rgba I need to call vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888 four times right? For each of value? Anyway.. don't work :/ Can't construct histogram constant like in your example. Did you tried?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This code produces "dangling pointers" warnings in Swift 5

Comment: Here is Apple's answer to the question https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/specifying_histograms_with_vimage

Comment: @ValeriyVan, thanks for that link! I used that link to create a Swift 5 version of shallowThought's code. The function I'm using explicitly names zero, one, two, three as red, green, blue, alpha.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

The code from shallowThought works, but for Swift 5 generates warnings:

```
Initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>' 
(aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>') results in a dangling pointer
```

To follow up Valerly Van's comments to shallowThought's accepted answer, here's Swift 5 code that eliminates the warnings. The code below is copied, pasted, and mashed together from two sources.

Apple's example, "Specifying Histograms with vImage"
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/specifying_histograms_with_vimage

An SO post about generating and using histograms, [Swift 2.2 - Count Black Pixels in UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818720/swift-2-2-count-black-pixels-in-uiimage)

```
func histogram(image: UIImage) -> (red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt], alpha: [UInt]) {
let img: CGImage = CIImage(image: image)!.cgImage!

let imgProvider: CGDataProvider = img.dataProvider!
let imgBitmapData: CFData = imgProvider.data!
var imgBuffer = vImage_Buffer(
    data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(imgBitmapData)),
    height: vImagePixelCount(img.height),
    width: vImagePixelCount(img.width),
    rowBytes: img.bytesPerRow)

// bins: zero = red, green = one, blue = two, alpha = three
var binZero = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var binOne = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var binTwo = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var binThree = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)

binZero.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { zeroPtr in
    binOne.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { onePtr in
        binTwo.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { twoPtr in
            binThree.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { threePtr in
                
                var histogramBins = [zeroPtr.baseAddress, onePtr.baseAddress,
                                     twoPtr.baseAddress, threePtr.baseAddress]
                
                histogramBins.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
                    histogramBinsPtr in
                    let error = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(
                        &imgBuffer,
                        histogramBinsPtr.baseAddress!,
                        vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
                    
                    guard error == kvImageNoError else {
                        fatalError("Error calculating histogram: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return (binZero, binOne, binTwo, binThree)
}
```

Matching up the bins (zero, one, two, three) with (red, green, blue, alpha) happens to work for my current and rather limited use case.